# Work on Individual C Files in Netbeans?

Tags: c, netbeans, ide

Is it possible to create (or open existing) C program files in Netbeans without creating an entire project? Can these be later run and compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Netbeans as fancy oversized editor for C files, but if you want to build program from Netbeans, you will need a project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better served by a dedicated editor like geany if all you need is some little edits here and there.

If you want to make small programs, geany + the shell using your compiler manually is simpler when starting small.

You edit your code, save, then `gcc micode.c -o micode.exe` on the console and your ready.